# Navigation bar on mobile isn't opening?

Tags: html, css, debugging, mobile, navigationbar

All the code is visible through "inspect element" (CSS and HTML).

This is in regards to the website [adventuroustravelers.net/](http://adventuroustravelers.net/)

On mobile, the image for the menu bar is visible but clicking on it redirects to the same page and doesn't open the menu bar. I feel like I'm missing something extremely obvious but can't figure out what it is - can someone help me resolve this issue?

Comment: try to put your code on `$(document).ready(function(){});` and put your script tag either at the head or bottom of body tag

Comment: This didn't end up doing anything... any other suggestions?

Comment: can you post here your codes? It is much easier to troubleshoot with some codes

Comment: check this out http://stackoverflow.com/questions/2194992/jquery-is-not-defined